# How do I evaluate the surface integral ∫s F . dS

Tags: surface-integrals

How do I evaluate the surface integral $∫_s$ $F\cdot ds $

where $S$ is given by $\psi(r,\theta)=r\theta$**i** + $sin\theta$**j**$+r$**k**

for $0\le r \le 1,$ $ 0\le \theta \le2\pi$ and **F** $=2xz$ **i**+$2y$**j**

Do I start with $∫_s$ $F\cdot ds = ∫_0(x\dot{\,x}+y\dot{\,y})ds $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if Im wrong, Im not confident in calculus 3.

For parametric surfaces, there is this formula of $\iint_{S} F \cdot N dS = \iint_{D} F \cdot (r_u \times r_v) dA$. First calculate the partial derivatives of $\phi (r, \theta)$ with respect to r and $\theta$, which is $\phi_r = \theta i + k$ and $\phi_{\theta} = ri + cos \theta j$. Then compute the cross product of the two vectors $\phi_r$ and $\phi_{\theta}$, resulting in the vector $\phi_r \times \phi_{\theta} = -cos (\theta) i + rj+\theta cos(\theta) k$. Then just plug in the information to the formula.
The right hand side will turn out to be $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} -2r^{2} \theta cos (\theta) + 2rsin(\theta) dr d\theta$. Applying integration by parts on the left term for the second integral and just integrating the right term will yield an answer of zero.